# Shodan. Get all open ports for a net

Tags: python, cidr, port-scanning, shodan

I want to get all the open ports for a network with Shodan (I know I can use `nmap` but I want to carry this out with Shodan).

The problem is that the website only shows the "TOP Services", and I would like to be given all the services.

For example, for this net: 195.53.102.0/24 I am given the following ports:

```
TOP SERVICES
HTTP 15
HTTPS 2
DNS 2
FTP 2
IKE-NAT-T 1
```

But if I scan this net: 195.53.0.0/16, I am given these ports:

```
TOP SERVICES
HTTP 1,012
HTTPS 794
179 290
IKE 238
IKE-NAT-T 227
```

So I am missing services like `dns` and `ftp`.

I am trying with the API, from python:

```
import shodan

SHODAN_API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"

api = shodan.Shodan(SHODAN_API_KEY)

# Wrap the request in a try/ except block to catch errors
try:

    # Search Shodan


    results = api.search('net:195.53.102.0/24')
    for service in results['matches']:
        print service['ip_str']
        print service['port']

except shodan.APIError, e:
        print 'Error: %s' % e
```

And this is the results I get:

```
195.53.102.193
80
195.53.102.138
80
195.53.102.148
80
195.53.102.136
80
195.53.102.157
80
195.53.102.226
443
195.53.102.66
500
195.53.102.133
80
195.53.102.142
80
195.53.102.66
4500
195.53.102.141
80
195.53.102.131
21
195.53.102.152
53
195.53.102.153
21
195.53.102.209
80
195.53.102.132
53
195.53.102.226
80
195.53.102.147
80
195.53.102.142
443
195.53.102.178
80
195.53.102.135
143
195.53.102.146
80
195.53.102.143
80
195.53.102.144
80
```

Just 1 port per IP, and for example, this IP: 195.53.102.131 has ports 21, 80 and 443 open, my results say just:

```
195.53.102.131
21
```

Instead of:

```
195.53.102.131
21
80
443
```

So I want either to, from the website, be given all the ports/services instead of just the `TOP SERVICES` or, from the API, being able to get all the ports per IP, not just 1. Or if anyone has a better solution, I would like to hear it too.

As I said, I would like to perform it with Shodan, not nmap. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `api.search()` method, Shodan searches for a service banner and a service banner only has 1 port. If you want to return all the ports for a host, you should use `api.host()` instead. For example:

```
import shodan

SHODAN_API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"

api = shodan.Shodan(SHODAN_API_KEY)

# Wrap the request in a try/ except block to catch errors
try:
# Search Shodan
    results = api.search('net:195.53.102.0/24')
    for service in results['matches']:
        hostinfo = api.host(service['ip_str'])

        print service['ip_str']
        #Not sure if it's correct, but you should do something,
        #like this:
        for port in hostinfo['port']:
            print port

except shodan.APIError, e:
    print 'Error: %s' % e
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get a breakdown of the open ports on a network then you can use the **count()** method and ask for the **port** facet. And you can ask the API to return more than the top 5 ports if you specify the facet as a tuple:

```
import shodan

api = shodan.Shodan(YOUR API KEY)
result = api.count('net:195.53.102.0/24', facets=[['port', 20]])
```

The top 20 ports (if available) are then available in the **result['facets']['port']** property. And using the **count()** method doesn't use any API credits so it won't eat into your usage limits.